# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser not displaying alt tag as text

Tags: javascript, php, html, simple-html-dom

```
 <?
include('simple_html_dom.php');
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.saie.bolognafiere.it/it/partner/media-partner');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->getAttribute('ul#slider356 alt') as $element) 
       echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
?>
```

Actually I would like that all the alt tag content contained in the " ul id="slider356 " are displayed as text but my code is not working can someone help me ?

Thank you

Comment: I prefer `DOMDocument` over `simple_html_dom`, but I'm fairly sure `getAttribute` doesn't work like that...

Comment: according to the docs (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) I think you want `foreach($html->find('ul#slider356') as $element) echo $element->alt . '<br>';`. Although unless the html is invalid, it will only have 1 result as ids (`#slider356`) are supposed to be unique.

Comment: `alt` is an attribute of the `img` tag, within an `a` tag, within a `li` tag, within the `ul#slider356` tag. Your selector needs to reflect that. Attributes and elements are different - @Sean's comment shows the correct way to access attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete Sean's comment, there is two ways to get the attribute's value:

1. `$node->attribute;`
2. `$node->getAttribute('attribute');`

So, in your case, try this:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.saie.bolognafiere.it/it/partner/media-partner');

// Find all images inside ul#slider356
foreach($html->find('ul#slider356 img') as $element)
    // Print alt value
    echo $element->alt . "<br/>";
    // $element->getAttribute('alt') should work as well
```

<kbd>[Working code](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/x17g-t4em)</kbd>

Please check the <kbd>[Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)</kbd> for more info...